# Where should I use anti forgery header verification in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, csrf

I'm using web API in asp.net. Also i'm trying to secure my API against *CSRF attacks*.

I tried to use the following tutorial from [Microsoft documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks).

In the Anti-CSRF and AJAX section, I successfully put the `RequestVerificationToken` header in the AJAX code. So the header is ok but i don't know where should i use the `ValidateRequestHeader` function mentioned in the tutorial.

```
void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string cookieToken = "";
    string formToken = "";

    IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
    if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestVerificationToken", out tokenHeaders))
    {
        string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
        if (tokens.Length == 2)
        {
            cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
            formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
        }
    }
    AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
```

Please help me with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom attribute which implements `FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter`.

And add it on top of your `Controller`/`Action` you want to validate.

You can find many guide on this subject.

Comment: in which file i should add this function? can you give an example?